# Question about load balancing

Tags: linux, load-balancing, file-sharing, server-message-block

As the title states just a quick question about load balancing

Was reading the following article:
http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/46735

And it got me thinking ...
We currently have a DFSR site and at current are remapping clients network drives to their closest location. I know it wouldn't be ideal but going for a Proof of concept maybe for DR / BC ..

Could you set up the linux load balancer using the SMB file sharing ports to distribute the connections between the servers equally?

I.e Client --> Linux LB Server --> one of the File Servers

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that using a proper clustering filesystem would be more effective then attempting to retrofit it onto SMB.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at **ldirectord** to accomplish this.

We use ldirectord to load balance our web servers, but I'm pretty sure it's flexible enough to work with file servers as well.  It can distribute connections in a number of ways, such as "least connected", "fastest response time", "round robin" etc (all the options available ipvsadm)